# linking error with c++ and mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I have to make a mex fil, so a wrote it and now I have some trouble with the compilation

i use the syntax:

```
mex CSerialCommunicator.cpp -I"./Inc"
```

and it always give me a linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

I think it because I don't have a main function, but I don't want to have it, i want to use my CSerialCommunicator like a library.

so, could you help me ?

Comment: Are you creating a dll library using code generated by matlab? if so did you created a main method? this is the entry point

Comment: @Ahmedsafan, i create a class for serial communication in c++ and i want to use it with matlab as a mex file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

-install visual studio 2005 professionnal edition sp1, and calling **mex -setup**.

now everything works.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

For mex files you must define an entry point (like `main` function in regular files).

The entry point for mex functions must have this signature:

```
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] );
```

For more details see [matlab's doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html).

Comment: yes this is exactly what I wrote in my cpp file this is why I don't understand the error

Comment: @Excelio do you have namespaces? are you sure `mexFunction` is in global scope?

Comment: @Excelio are you using the exact prototype ?
`void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, 
  const mxArray *prhs[]);`

Comment: @Shai sure, i try with a class definition then I saw that it doesn't work, so i try with just function definition into a .h but I also had the same error

Comment: @Excelio can you add to the post a code example? Please do not post your entire code - only a tiny sample that reproduces the error you are experiencing

Comment: @Shai it's just the verbose mode, i've tried but nothing important

Comment: @Excelio have you tried re-configuring your `mex` compiler? calling `mex -setup` again?

Comment: @Shai yes, i've tried many times but it didn't works however I thinnk the problem comes from the compiler

Comment: @Excelio I believe you are using visual studio compiler under windows architecture? what versions of matlab/windows/visualStudio are you using?

Comment: @Shai I used the visual stuio 2008 compiler under matlab r2007b
i don't have these line in the compiler's output :s

Comment: @Excelio you should see those flags for the `link` command not the `cl` command.

Comment: @Shaiok, but how can i do this ?

Comment: first try it out manually in command line - type the command and all paramneters in a windows terminal. if this solves your problem, you should hack the mexopt file to insert these link flags.